# querying instance mac address for system

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to figure out how to add the mac address per instance via the AWS CLI for windows.

I currently have this one running well that shows the instance ID, name, state, and public/private IP:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value|[0],State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,PublicIpAddress]" --output text
```

Now I just want the Mac address added to the end of the list, but am having the hardest time with syntax. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Did NetworkInterfaces[0].MacAddress not work?

Comment: @jarmod oh my gosh, it was a user error. I tried NetworkInterface[0].MacAddress and left off the s on interface. this worked just fine. Thank you for the help. I feel rather foolish now :X

Comment: Haha! Nice. Glad this was an easy fix. Can you mark it as answered please. @Sh3perd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indicate `NetworkInterfaces[0].MacAddress` to get the MAC address of the first network interface.